# compute The quotient

Tags: abstract-algebra

Iam trying to find what is the  quotient of ZxZ by the commutator subgroup (ZxZ/[a,b]) and also the quotient of Z/2ZxZ/2Z by the commutator subgroup(Z/2ZxZ/2Z/[a,b])?

Any idea?

Thank you

Comment: What are $a$ and $b$? Anyway, $\mathbb{Z}$ is abelian and so is the direct product of two copies of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ is an abelian group, so the commutator subgroup is trivial, hence the quotient is again $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$. Nothing changes when you consider $\mathbb{Z}_2$ instead of $\mathbb{Z}$.